# Create an (almost) never-ending line using monogame

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monogame

I'm struggling with a problem. I want to create a line which starts off flat, then curves a little upwards, then curve down again and then flattens out. I don't know the best way to do this, but this has to be done programatically and somewhat random. I started to try to draw a straight line with a texture. What I did was:

```
protected override void Update (GameTime gameTime)
    {
        float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        screenpos.X += elapsed + 1;
        base.Update (gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw (GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //GraphicsDevice.Clear (Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin ();
        spriteBatch.Draw(dot, screenpos, null, Color.White, RotationAngle, origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
        spriteBatch.End ();

        base.Draw (gameTime);

    }
```

So now I have a beautiful straight line with the texture. But what should I do to create a curve? I want to draw the next texture, with a rotation, at the end of the last drawn texture. But I'm struggling with what the coordinates to the last drawn texture is. Do someone have any links or any ideas how I should attack this problem? I'm developing via monogame and xamarin if that makes any difference.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking to create a [Gaussian function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function)?

Answer (score 0):

I would store a list of `Vector2` positions and draw line segments between them. The distance between the points should be small to achieve a nice looking line.